# Is there any solution for make my own Meteor cloud server?

Tags: meteor

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

When I run this command line, my meteor app upload to meteor cloud server.

Is there any solution or repository for make my own meteor cloud server?

```
meteor deploy mycloud.server.com myapp.mydomain.com
```

I know I can use my own domain use this command.

```
meteor deploy myapp.mydomain.com
```

But I want to make my own cloud service like **meteor do**.

[image]

I know https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up. But this is single service solution.
This is not for one or more server (clustered server) with many services.

If there are no solution for this, I'll make this solutions.

Comment: I think I can make this with Deis(http://deis.io/) with docker. This is great solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now [galaxy](https://trello.com/c/FMdB7GAu/78-galaxy-managed-meteor-deploy-to-your-own-servers) is still not released, this one should do exactly what you are looking for i.e. using deploy on your own server.

An alternative might be [modulus.io](http://blog.modulus.io/deploying-meteor-apps-on-modulus) but it is still not the easy deployment we would like.

The simplest I found yet is still using [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). You can use it for deploying on several server too. The point is meteor-up expect to have a running ubuntu (or debian), and you deploy to those machines. You still need to setup an oplog for mongodb and a high availability proxy (with sticky session) to forward on the right virtual machines….

If only the performances matter, you can build micro services and integrated them through a service discovery as provided through [meteorhacks:cluster](https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster#practical-setup), as this will help load balance your app it does not (yet?) provide a way to route the client according to the domain name (meaning you still need a reverse proxy for accessing the right service discovery from a domain) Also this packages does not provide any way to deploy you app, this is just a convenient way to help manage and scale your service.

If you need a reliable solution right now, docking meteor, deploying it on clusters and managing them, I would strongly advise looking at: https://bulletproofmeteor.com It is a very good source for building reliable meteor app with high availability. Note that all the chapters are not free, but there is a whole chapter covering "Deploying Meteor Apps into a Kubernetes Cluster" which goes step by step on the process of setting up your server(s) for running your meteor app in a PaaS way.